# height of the div doesnot resizing with incresing content in twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter-bootstrap and when the content of a div is increased, height of the div doesn't resize with increasing content.

Comment: Well that's a bummer. Do you have some code? Or is it _all in your head_? :D

Comment: check height, max-height, position and overflow in the css for that element

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry folks!! there was an error in nesting the divs and the content inside! I got it working by correcting that. thanks anyway.